# Android Volley file sending with Apache: NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: ContentType

Tags: java, android, apache

I need to upload the file to the server from the Android app. I'm using `Volley` and created the class, which help to send the data with the help of `multipart`:

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String> {

    MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    HttpEntity httpentity;
    private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "image ";

    private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
    private final File mFilePart;
    private final Map<String, String> mStringPart;

    public MultipartRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener,
                            Response.Listener<String> listener, File file,
                            Map<String, String> mStringPart) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
        mListener = listener;
        mFilePart = file;
        this.mStringPart = mStringPart;
        entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        buildMultipartEntity();
    }

    public void addStringBody(String param, String value) {
        mStringPart.put(param, value);
    }

    private void buildMultipartEntity() {
        entity.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, new FileBody(mFilePart));
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mStringPart.entrySet()) {
            entity.addTextBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return httpentity.getContentType().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            httpentity = (HttpEntity) entity.build();
            httpentity.writeTo(bos);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        return Response.success("Uploaded", getCacheEntry());
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

I'm using `Gradle`, so my dependencies:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1'
```

tried to implement the libraries in the libs folder, but got issues during the project building. 
When I make the request in this way, I receive:

```
      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;

     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.entity.ContentType" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/android.demigos.comouts-1/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib/egl, system/lib/hw]]
```

My Gradle file:

```
  android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.demigos.comouts"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    ......
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
}
```

And remove this line:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1'
```

Comment: Already did. But then I can't import the MultipartEntityBuilder

Comment: ok try to add this dependency: compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4"

Comment: and add your build.gradle file to your question

Comment: And when I changed to 4.2.4 - the same as when I removed this.